# How to delete data from more than 1 week ago in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I created a web-scraper to store data for a week to find a trend.
I wrote code to delete data from more than week ago every time the script runs.
However the data is still being stored for more than a week ago, is there a reason for this?"

example coin data createdAt field looks like

```
    "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2021-08-11T10:55:19.843Z"
},

coinSchema.statics.deleteOldData = async function () {
  // delete old data
  const today = new Date(Date.now());
  today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  const oneWeekAgo = new Date(Date.now());
  const pastDate = oneWeekAgo.getDate() - 7;
  oneWeekAgo.setDate(pastDate);

  await this.deleteMany({
    createdAt: {
      $gte: today,
    }, // 16 < 17 wont delete it prevent duplicates for one day
  });
  await this.deleteMany({
    createdAt: {
      $lt: pastDate,
    }, // from 1 week ago
  });
};
```

in the script i have the this run

```
async function main() {
await Coin.deleteOldData();
```

my coin model looks like :

```
    const coinSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    specNo: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    coinName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    fullName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    category: {
      type: String,
    },
    array: [
      {
        GradeName: String,
        PopulationCount: String,
        trend: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: How does your collection data look like? Perhaps you store date values as string (which is a design flaw) instead of proper `Date` objects.

Comment: When working with Dates then I recommend the [moment.js library](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Would be `createdAt: { $lt: moment().startOf('day').subtract(7, 'day').toDate() }` and `createdAt: { $gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate() }`

Comment: "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-08-11T10:55:19.843Z"
    },

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at TTL based index? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/

This is a good way to cleanup old data where DB itself takes care of it. In your case 7 days is 604800 seconds so if you create a index on createdAt with ttl 604800 then you should be all good!

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "createdAt ": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 604800 } )
```

Comment: Do I put this in the model? or in my web scraper?

Comment: this index is created on DB server. usually DBA would do index creation. Also this is one time setup. once you setup TTL based index you are all set!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.deleteMany({
  createdAt: { $lte: new Date(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toISOString() },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal: `mongosh`
Change to your database: `use your_db_name`

```
db.your_collection.createIndex( { "createdAt ": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 604800 } )
```

You can verify TTL index creation in Mongo Compass -> Your DB/Collection -> Indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to let you know, someone else already suggested the same solution. To keep things fresh, it'd be great if you could share a different approach or insight. This way, we can bring more variety to the table and give the community more to think about. Thanks